# c++ stl selection for multiple keys

Tags: c++, stl

c++ stl experts,
In a protocol stack implementation, I have a Message being sent from one layer to another. The source layer stores some information, and processes that information, on recepton of response from the second layer.

Now the information stored has 3 parameters which is used to compare the responses from the destination layer. (to get the correct one). i.e lets says session id, request number and infoID. The stored info contains a struture, lets say struct A.

which is the best way to implement this in the source layer to store info ?

Initially i thought of the following, as then there were only two keys

```
 std::map<std::pair<u32, u32>, StructA> m_mSessionId2RNum2StructA;
```

But later requirement for another key. this got complicated

```
struct StructZ
{
     u32 InfoId;
     StructA stStructA;
};

std::map<std::pair<u32, u32>, StructZ> m_mSessionId2RNum2StructZ;
```

This doesnot look good. Any inputs/suggestions to improve this much appreciated
thanks
~pdk

Comment: hat is your exact question?

Comment: @AB_ Which is the best way to implement with multiple keys ? Why downvote !

Comment: downvote is not from me

Comment: @AB_ sorry : It was by mistake put in the same comment as to your reply

Comment: As I understand the issue, you cannot use `pair` any more, because you need more then two element combination as a compound key. So, did you consider making class or other struct (with three integer fields) as a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `StructK` can be a key for `StructA` as a value in a map:

```cpp
struct StructK
{
     u32 k1;
     u32 k2;
     u32 k3;
};

inline bool operator< (const StructK& lhs, const StructK& rhs)
{
    if(lhs.k1 < rhs.k1)
        return true;
    else
        if(lhs.k1 == rhs.k1)
        {
            if(lhs.k2 < rhs.k2)
                return true;
            else
                if(lhs.k2 == rhs.k2)
                {
                    return lhs.k3 < rhs.k3;
                }
                else
                    return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
}
```

and then

```
 map<StructK, StructA> myMap;
```

Of course, you can use any logic for `operator<`

Answer (score 0):

`std::pair` is a special type of `std::tuple` which can only hold two values, whereas `tuple` can hold dozens (1). I.e. you seem to want `std::tuple<u32, u32,u32>` as a key now.

You get `operator<` for free with `tuple`, same as with `pair`.

If you need *alternate* indices, i.e. search by key 1, 2 *or* 3, then you need `boost::multi_index` containers.

(1) Check your implementation for precise limits.